# Was bedeutet "Ein Satz mit X, das war wohl nix"?

Tags: meaning, usage, phrase, idiom

Ich habe eine E-Mail bekommen, in der ein deutscher Freund von mir folgenden Satz geschrieben hat:

> Bei uns gibt es einen Spruch: »Nenne mir einen Satz mit X: Das war wohl nix.«

Da ich diesen Ausdruck nicht kenne, habe ich ihn gesucht und [diese Seite über Redensarten](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=ein%20Satz%20mit%20X%20das%20war%20wohl%20nix&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_varianten_ou) gefunden. Die Bedeutung ist:

> die Hoffnung / Erwartung wurde nicht erfüllt; das Vorhaben konnte nicht realisiert werden.

Und noch dazu:

> umgangssprachlich, salopp; Die scherzhafte Redewendung wird bei einem Scheitern oder einer Enttäuschung benutzt. [...] Die orthographisch falsche Schreibweise "nix" statt "nichts" [...] trägt hier den scherzhaften Charakter.

Dann verstehe ich, worauf sich mein Freund bezieht. Aber ich verstehe den Ausdruck immer noch nicht, nicht ganz.

Warum »ein Satz mit X«? Ist es nur, um den Gesprächspartner zu überraschen und zum Lachen zu bringen, weil der Satz eigentlich kein echtes X enthält? Oder gibt's etwas Anderes? Zum Beispiel: Gibt es einen »normalen«, »erwarteten« Satz mit X, an den man normalerweise denken würde? Gibt's eine Bedeutung, die ich nicht verstehe?

Comment: userunknown sagt zurecht, dass das Ganze nur ein witziger Reim ist. Meist wird übrigens nur erste Teil "Satz mit X" ausgesprochen. Den zweiten Teil "War wohl nix" (d.h. *da hast Du Mist gebaut* oder *Du hast versagt*) denkt sich praktisch jeder Hörer dazu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Bedeutung der Redewendung hast du ja schon selbst rausgesucht, darum werde ich darauf nicht weiter eingehen.

"Nix" bedeutet umgangssprachlich nichts anderes als "Nichts". Darum kann man den ersten Teil der Redewendung wortwörtlich nehmen: Ein Satz mit X (was aussagen soll: ein Satz der ein X beinhaltet) ist wie man sieht "Das war wohl ni**x**". Der erste Teil der Redewendung bezieht sich also auf kein beliebiges X, sondern leitet den zweiten Satz ein und bezieht sich nur auf den. Der dadurch erreichte Reim unter dem Motto "Reim dich oder ich fress dich" verstärkt dazu den augenzwinkernden Ansatz.

Statt also bei einem Scheitern einer anderen Person zu sagen "Das war wohl nichts" und dabei strenger als gewollt oder sogar tadelnd zu wirken, kann man diese humoristische, ironische Redewendung benutzen.

Answer (score 2):

1. "Ein Satz mit X" follows the pattern of crossword-puzzle cues, like "a city with six letters, starts with L". Such phrases are usually not intonated with the raising tone of a question. Thus, in the given case, it works as a rhetorical question. As rhetorical as it is, it does not per se offer enough information about the puzzle.
2. "Das war wohl nix" is the solution to the puzzle. It is also a statement about the situation. It is suggested that the context in the given situation offers enough additional information to solve the puzzle. The fact that the solution is offered immediately may alternatively suggest two things, either a) that you would never have guessed the solution, because you were unaware of the situation, or b) that the answer is obvious, as may be the case especially when already familiar with the idiom.
3. In either case it is a play on the basic statement *das war wohl nix*, ie. *that*, whatever had just been attempted, *was certainly not succesful*.
4. In particular, it can be played as a call and response by posing the question to somebody – which may be perceived as childish or playful. At any rate, it is supposed to be jocular.

PS: A similar callback is this: *Wie heißt das Zauberwort mit zwei T?*; Expected *Bitte*; Being mean: *Aber flott!* – when somebody forgot to say please, ie. *Bitte*.

Answer (score 1):

Nein, da ist eine große semantische Leere, die einfach nichts weiter bedeutet. Ein Reim, der vielleicht auch eine milde Schadenfreude ausdrückt und zu erheitern versucht, aber im normalen Sprachgebrauch sagt man sonst nie "Satz mit X - Klebefix" oder "Satz mit U - Uhu" oder sonstwas in der Art, von spontanen Kreativbildungen abgesehen, die sich Lankwitz oder Döberitz ereignet haben mögen.

Apropos:

> Kurzer Witz: Lankwitz.

Comment: Nicht ganz gleich, aber etwas ähnliches gibt es schon: »Tschüß mit Ü« und davon abgewandelt: »Tschau mit Au« (Wobei *»tschau«* eine eigentlich falsche Schreibweise des italienischen Wortes *»ciao«* ist, in dem gar kein *»au«* vorkommt)

Comment: "Tschö mit Ö" kenne ich auch, aber zumindest in meine Hörweite kam das später, viel später. "Tschüß mit Ü" ist dagegen gar kein richtiger Reim.

Comment: Ü wird neuerdings als Lachgesicht gebraucht, oft am Satzende. Daher, sowie es keinen Endreim bildet, vermute ich doch mal, dass der "Reim" aus der aktuellen Schriftsprache stammen müsste als Abwandlung auf *... Ö*, welches die einzige mir bisher bekannte Form wäre.